# Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined, when trying to return object from function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a function to get the positions of elements, but when I try to get the bottom offset it return **not defined**, what am I missing?

This is my attempt:

```
var myDiv = jQuery('.div');

function getOffset(el) {
    var off = jQuery(el).offset();
    return {
        left: off.left,
        right: off.left + el.outerWidth(),
        top: off.top,
        bottom: off.top + el.outerHeight(),
        hCenter: (bottom + top) /2,
        wCenter: (right + left) /2
    };
}

var myDivPosition = getOffset(myDiv);

console.log(
        "top = " + myDivPosition.top +
        "bottom = " + myDivPosition.bottom +
        "hCenter = " + myDivPosition.hCenter +
        "left = " + myDivPosition.left +
        "right = " + myDivPosition.right +
        "wCenter = " + myDivPosition.wCenter
        );
```

I get in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bottom is not defined

Comment: bottom & right used in hcenter & wcenter are not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `bottom` and `right` variables you haven't declared. Note that using an unqualified `bottom` or `right` identifer doesn't in any way retrieve them from the object you're building (in fact, [there is no reasonable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)). So just do them up-front (you also need to refer to `top` and `left` on `off`):

```
function getOffset(el) {
    var off = jQuery(el).offset();
    var bottom = off.top + el.outerHeight();  // ***
    var right = off.left + el.outerWidth();   // ***
    return {
        left: off.left,
        right: right,                         // ***
        top: off.top,
        bottom: bottom,                       // ***
        hCenter: (bottom - off.top) /2,       // ***
        wCenter: (right - off.left) /2        // ***
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help!

Comment: also, it sounds like I was missing declaring `top` and `left` as well ?

Comment: @Homer: I missed you were doing it with `top` and `left` as well. You don't have to declare them, you can just use `off.top` and `off.left` in the code. I've updated the answer.